# “Failed to open stream: permission denied” when starting a PHP server on Mac

Tags: php, macos

I'm trying to start a PHP server on Mac:

```
php -S localhost:8000 –t basic/web
```

But I get the following errors:

```
[Thu Dec 11 22:35:32 2014] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Dec 11 22:35:32 2014] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '–t' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Dec 11 22:35:32 2014] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Dec 11 22:35:32 2014] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '–t' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: What directory are you in when you invoke this command? Did you try using an absolute path for the document root (like `/Users/username/Documents/basic/web`)? What are the permissions and ownership for `basic/web`?

Comment: Permissions: drwxr-xr-x

Comment: Unfortunately, trying an absolute path doesn't work. I'm in /Users/User/Desktop/yii when I invoke the command

Comment: And `basic/web` is within `/Users/User/Desktop/yii`?

Comment: Yes, basic/web is within /Users/User/Desktop/yii